# HDMI No Signal on LG TV (but works on other TVs)

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, raspberry-pi-os, osmc

I was at my parent’s for the weekend and I used the time to setup OSMC on my new RPi 4.
They have an older (~10 years) Samsung TV and everything worked fine (including CEC or whatever it’s called on Samsung).

I came home today and excitedly tried to connect the RPi to my LG TV (bought it almost 2 years ago) and i was disappointed seeing No Signal on it. I tried all the ports combinations (both tv and RPi).

I also have some very very cheap generic TV (~5 years old) and on it everything works fine too! Same device, same cable, etc.

I also have an older RPi 3 with the latest OSMC on it. Tried it on the LG TV and everything works fine. The only difference is the cable. On the RPi 3, I have a regular HDMI cable, not the smaller one as it is on RPi 4.

Next, I did a backup of my SD card and tried putting a fresh copy of OSMC on it, but with no luck. Still “No signal”.

**I tried the same with LibreELEC and Raspberry Pi OS and got the same result.**

With a fresh OSMC image, I moved the device to the older tv and (as everything works there) i finished the installation and connected the device to the wifi.

Then i connected it to the LG TV again. Still nothing.

Here’s my log after I connected it to the LG: https://paste.osmc.tv/uvefojineg

(After i set the log level to 2: https://paste.osmc.tv/lesuzeqeru)
I tried many things i could find where not, but couldn’t achieve anything.

Also, here's the log of the RPi3 device with a fresh OSMC installation when connected to the LG TV - https://paste.osmc.tv/ozodabiyiq (everything works for this device on the same TV)

Comment: I don't recognize where that "log" came from, but I am curious -- it is not the system log and looks more like a configuration report. Try adding `hdmi_safe=1` to `/boot/config.txt` and reboot.  If this works the setting can be fine tuned.  See: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#hdmi-configuration

Comment: @goldilocks I'm using grab-logs from OSMC to upload the logs. I had already tried setting `hdmi_safe=1` but didn't help. Tried it again now but with no luck..

Comment: Here are the logs after the hdmi_safe config was set - https://paste.osmc.tv/mumopatagu (this should contain all the configuration and logs as I've understood the tool)

Comment: I've never used OMSC so that explains that.  There is normal linux kernel log in there with repeated HDMI errors, but I couldn't tell you what they mean specifically. Could be all that's left to you is to try a different (shorter and/or heavier gauge) cable...

Comment: Thanks. If the cable was the problem wouldn't it cause problems on the other TVs as well? I'm using the same cables everywhere?

Comment: What is the resolution of your LG TV?

Comment: @CoderMike 3840x2160

Comment: Is that 4K? You might need hdmi_enable_4kp60=1

Comment: Already tried that but didn't help :/

Comment: *"If the cable was the problem wouldn't it cause problems on the other TVs as well?"* -> Maybe not, since cables can definitely be the problem (I've observed this in contexts other than the pi), but cables that don't work at all for anything are probably unusual (distributors and retailers would stop carrying them etc), implying there are cables that are OK for some things but fail for others.  It is sort of a last resort, esp. since a high quality HDMI cable can cost almost as much as the Pi itself...